# conditional breakpoint does not work in windbg

Tags: windbg, breakpoints

I have following c++ code

```
int myvar=1;

void test1( int j)
{
    int b=j+1;
}


void main()
{

myvar=2;
    test1(50);      


    myvar=3;
    test1(100);     


    myvar=6;
    test1(200);     

}
```

I'm trying to set a breakpoint that stops if myvar is greater than 4 when running function test1.

Here is my breakpoint:

```
bp test!test1 ".if ( poi(myvar)>0n4) {} .else {gc} "
```

however, it stops every time test1 is executed...
The executable file is called test.exe, a 64 bit application.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: use c++ expression evaluator myvar is a c++ expression not masm expression bp condbp!test1 ".if( @@(myvar)<4 ) {?? myvar;gc}"

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of debugging in the breakpoint reveals what is happening:

```
 0 e Disable Clear  00007ff6`77e11410  [f:\projects\windbg_help\main.cpp @ 4]     0001 (0001)  0:**** windbg_help!test1 "?? myvar; r $t1=myvar; ?? @$t1; r $t2=poi(myvar); ?? @$t2;  .if (dwo(myvar) > 0n4) {.echo yes; gc} .else {.echo no; gc} "
```

I set the t1 temp register to myvar, and t2 temp register to the contents of myvar, then display them:

```
0:000> g
int 0n2
unsigned int64 0x00007ff6`77e1c000
unsigned int64 0xffffffff`00000002
no
int 0n3
unsigned int64 0x00007ff6`77e1c000
unsigned int64 0xffffffff`00000003
no
int 0n6
unsigned int64 0x00007ff6`77e1c000
unsigned int64 0xffffffff`00000006
yes
ModLoad: 00007ff9`c8520000 00007ff9`c8531000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`c9da0000 00007ff9`c9e3e000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`c9aa0000 00007ff9`c9bc2000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0x14:
00007ff9`cc5cfcd4 c3              ret
```

Notice how poi(myvar) is returning a 64bit value, and the upper 32bits are set. You poi(myvar) > 0n4 comparison is saying:

```
if (0xffffffff0000000? > 4) then { always true }
```

use dwo(myvar) instead to read only the 32bit contents

Comment: Thanks Chris. the dwo works for me.  However, do you have docs about the dwo, i don't find anything online...

Comment: Is dwo a replacement of poi in 64bit?

Comment: Search in windbg help for "MASM Numbers and Operators" you will see a table of possible options, which include dwo (Double-word from the specified address) , qwo (Quad-word from the specified address), etc